# HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm wondering why my code doesn't work at random when I try to login but when I close the browser and recompile the code,it will work like normal.

The error usually come when I logout after successfully login, then when I try to re login this error come out in chrome:

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

When I try to open in IE,this come Out:

```
(HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed)
```

in console error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

this is my SecurityConfig:

```
.formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl( "/login" )
            .loginPage( "/login.do" )
            .defaultSuccessUrl( "/",true )
            .failureUrl( "/login.do?error" )
            .usernameParameter( "username" )
            .passwordParameter( "password" )
            .permitAll()
            .and()
```

If you need any code,just tell me.

Added @RequestMapping:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = {"/login.do" }, method ={ RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
        @RequestParam(value = "timeout", required = false) String timeout,
        @RequestParam(value = "expired", required = false) String expired,
        @RequestParam(value = "invalid", required = false) String invalid, 
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
    if (session != null) { 
        sessionClear(request, response);
    }

    Context context;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jndi/CMS");
        Connection c = ds.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");

    }
    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    if (expired != null) {
        model.addObject("exp", "You've been logged out due to expired.");

    }

    model.setViewName("log_in");
    logger.trace("this is trace");
    logger.debug("This is a debug");
    logger.info("this is info");
    logger.warn("This is warn");
    logger.error("This is error");



    return model;
}
```

Update:
I realize if I compile and login in new window,its always work as normal,but if I recompile the code and execute in new tab,the error will trigger.

Comment: The logs you are seeing indicate the error is due to your `@RequestMapping` within Spring MVC controllers (not anything to do with Spring Security). Please include the URL that is being requested and the complete logs for that request.

Comment: What do you mean by including the URL being request and complete log?

Comment: What URL are you posting to when you get the error? Can you post the rest of the logs from your console?

Comment: The error always trigger when it goes to either /j_spring_security_check or /login . Log only show the 2 line ,org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound and org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver

Comment: somehow I already resolve the error,but new error come out:

`Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?`

Comment: Please see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason,the problem has been solve.
I have change back my spring security to use /logout URL to invalidate session in spring security. Before this i use :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    try {
        request.logout();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    request.getSession().invalidate();
```

to invalidate session,then when i change to logout base on spring security which is either `/j_spring_security_logout` or `/logout`,the problem seem to solve.Maybe my programmatically logout cannot logout and invalidate session properly.
Thanks for help.