# Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf-protection

I am trying to implement a simple login page with Spring security. Whatever I do, I always get an error `Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported` when submitting form input. 
**Related files:**
SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/thank-you", "/faq", "/legal", "/policy").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/");
    }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{

}
```

part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginPage(  )
{
    return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/views/login");
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

login.jsp:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
<div>
  <label for="j_username">Username</label> <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="j_username" name="ssoId" required />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="j_password">Password</label> <br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="j_password" name="password" required />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}" />

<div class="form-actions">
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</div>
```

I think the problem is with the fact that my $(_csrf.parameterName} and ${_csrf.token} are both empty when Inspecting them. If you need any additional information, I would be happy to supply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have figured it out. I did the following changes to the code in my question: 
In `web.xml` I had to add:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

login.jsp:

```
<form name='loginForm' action="/login" method='POST'>
<div>
  <label for="username">Username</label> <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="password">Password</label> <br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}" />

<div class="form-actions">
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</div>
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin").failureUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .csrf();
}
```

Hope it helps someone in a similar need.

Answer (score 2):

i know it's a 3 years old question, but my answer can help others. So, i had this situation also; and i've found out that Spring CSRF don't allow POST Method. so what i did is disabling CSRF and manually send the CSRF Tokens like below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin").failureUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

and in the JSP file :

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

No permit for login page ?

```
.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
```

I give you some example for login page :

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
    .and()
    .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/main", true)
    .failureUrl("/login.do?error")
    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but this still produces the exact same error :/

Comment: I got same problem as you,but also not sure what has been resolve  :(
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080594/http-405-method-not-allowed

Answer (score -1):

Your form action specifies

```
action="/login"
```

And your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

My guess is that your form submit gets matched to the controller method and that is why you get the exception.

You can try and change your submit url in the form or specify somehow in the authorizeRequests() method to accept /login from POST.

Comment: You can have the same URL in your controller as long as it isn't`RequestMethod.POST`.